# Extra space on mobile with Twitter Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am Using the Twitter Bootstrap 4 code below I am getting extra space where the picture element is. When I remove the picture element from the column (so the tag is empty) the extra space obvious does not show. If I add some "lorem ipsum text" instead of the picture element the extra space shows.

The element with the text "content" inside does not show any extra space - the no-gutters class takes care of this.

I've run into this in the past and just removed the extra space with CSS, but obviously, that should not be the solution if you're using a framework like Bootstrap 4 (4.3.1).

Looking forward to your suggestions.

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
.container{
  padding: 0px;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: #0D1954 !important;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.white-background {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
<style>
```

The html code is as followed.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-block d-lg-none">
            <div class="col-12">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="https://picsum.photos/600/300" type="image/webp" class="img-fluid">
                    <source srcset="https://picsum.photos/600/300" type="image/jpeg" class="img-fluid"> 
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" class="img-fluid">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-12 white-background ">
                content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the code on fiddle: [Bootstrap Code on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcwitteveen/p0mw1boy/7/)

[image: Extra space added on Twitter Bootstrap 4]

Comment: Can you give us a code sample that we can run? You can do so in the Stackoverflow editor itself or via a fiddle. It's difficult to help you if we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Helenesh thanks for the suggestion - I've updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the padding of 0 pixels in the container CSS class.

```
.container{
    padding:0;
}
```

which used to have a padding of 15 pixels with a row having a margin of -15 pixels. Comes to 0 pixels.

When I make the container have 0 padding and keep the row of -15 pixels the whole thing becomes a mess.

To solve this either put a no-gutter class on the row or a px-0 class on the row or add a

```
.row {
    margin:0;
}
```

class to your stylesheet and the "weird" horizontal slider disappears.